# Spotify localStorage to file/database?

Tags: local-storage, spotify

Im trying to get the localStorage data into some sort of saveable file for future access. I can get the data into localStorage but how can i get it either into a database or a file of some sort. I was thinking of just dumping all the keys into csv file or something but im really not sure what the best way to go would be... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spotify Apps API doesn't provide any local storage capabilities other than the standard Local Storage APIs. If you need something more, you'll need to upload the data to a web service for storage there.